# In PHP, is it possible to encrypt a string using a key that someone who has full access to the code would not know?

Tags: php, encryption

I'm looking to encrypt secure data, such as social security numbers, but there will be other people (e.g. my web host, employees) who have full access to the source code of the encryption. Is it possible to somehow encrypt using a key that does not need to be included in the original source, such that only I (who would know the key) would be able to decrypt?

Answer (score 3):

The way you're thinking about it, no, it can't be done. No, just saying "asymmetric encryption" won't help either. When certain operations are gonna accrue on those data (by a legitimate user) you'd have to decrypt them and wherever your decryption key is stored you're code is gonna try to access is it (meaning that any admin on the server can access it too).

Of course if you want to encrypt the clients' data in a semi-permenant fashion (the users won't be able to alter or read the data again) then yes, the people who suggested asymmetric encryption with you (the developer) keeping the private key secret, are 100% right.

A way of doing it is the following:

1. User signing up: Generate key pair (private & public) store the public in the database, encrypt the private with the user's password's hash and store it in the database. Now hash the hashed password again and store it in the database.
2. User entering sensitive data: Take the input and encrypt it with the public key from the database (and as suggested by Hugo, use the user's password as the passphrase for the  process) and store it in the database.
3. User accessing/editing his information: Take the user's password, hash 2 times and authenticate him, then if he's a legitimate user then use the first hash to decrypt the private key and use the private key to decrypt the data (Using the user's password as the passphrase for the process).

Keep in mind that there's no 100% security, take this idea and improve it.

**Update**: I talked to a friend who works with a payment processing company, he described the real life situation as the following:

There's no way around it, the people running server will always have access to the data, encrypted or not. You have to keep the private key some where. We keep SSNs and Credit Card Numbers in a separate data database on a separate server that has physical security and only authorized people are allowed to access that server. We don't query the secure database except using scripts on the same server and those scripts provide us with bare-minimum API that will handle all the payments. In our plain-text database we keep only a portion of the information (XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-4569) for viewing purposes only. All editing, reading, appending, adding, removing happens on that secure server (secure software, locked doors, security cameras) through the API.

Comment: This is an excelent idea if you need to decrypt the data constantly.

Comment: Also, rather than encrypting the keys using the user's password, use that same password as the key's passphrase.  I'm pretty sure that using the password as the key's passphrase is more secure than hashing the private key, and it's what the passphrase is there for in the first place :)

Comment: May be it would be better just to use own virtual private server rather than encrypting? Also, what if user lost password? How can we access encrypted information in this case? Or the user will have to reenter his SSID after this procedure?

Comment: Oops! Losing the password thing! I'll think about some solution. About encryption, yes it's important, what if somehow someone accessed your database? Let's say the easiest way, SQL Injection

Comment: What happens if you loose the password?  The same thing that happens to any encrypted data if you loose the only password, it lost, forever.  It the price you pay for real security.  If there was any way to retreive it, then the encryption was pointless in the first place.

Comment: @Timur, @ Hugo. I asked a friend who works for a company that handles financial data and payments and update my answer with what he told me.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

You could, however, use assymetric keys, such as GPG keys (or SSL keys).

You have a private and public key.  The public key is used for encrypting, and the private key for decrypting.  You could include the public key in the source code, and only keep the private key to yourself.

Comment: That would be *asymmetric* keys.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I've fixed the answer accordingly.

Comment: woo.. you get me interested there, please tell me how would you implement asymmetric encryption in the OP's case.

Comment: @AdnanShammout: With a library.  I wouldn't implement crypto with my own algorithms unless I was a researcher.  I wouldn't implement an existing algorithm unless I was very first on the platform to do so.  There's way too many types and sources of bugs that could exist for me to trust a DIY approach.  As for how it would work at a high level, check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Comment: This reference manual should help you get started on this http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gnupg.php.  You'll need to generate the GPG keys beforehand, of course, and include the public key along with the source.  There's plenty of howtos and tutorials on the specifics if you google them.

Comment: That's great, but please just give me a basic idea (words, not code) about how will it apply in this case. Let's say the OP encrypted his client's data in a Database and now the client is logged in and certain data manipulation should happen (the user will edit those secret data) how's the system gonna decrypt them? From where does the "secretly stored" private get fetched? (same question to @Amber)

Comment: The data can only be decrypted using the private key, so the decrypting would have to be done elsewhere.  You most certainly can't do it using the program of which you'd share the source.  The only way around this, is to store the private key in another location on the server, and have PHP reference to it there.  However, anyone with access to the server would be able to decrypt the data.

Comment: See? That's my point. Wherever you store the private key on server (or somewhere else you're code can retrieve from) someone else will have access to it. So, how do you solve this? (No need to explain how asymmetric encryption works, I'm pretty sure I have a basic idea about that)

Comment: Well the op's question didn't state that the application needed to decrypt the data, I assumed the PHP application just encrypted the data and it was to be read elsewhere.

Comment: @Hugo, come on. How creepy would it be that the clients would store their sensitive data and he's home with his private key reading the data :D

Answer (score 0):

you could use [mcrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php)

**example encoding:**

```
$key = "mykey";
$data = "my data";
$enc_data = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, md5($key));
```

**example decoding:**

```
$data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $enc_data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

the $key can be given outside of source code or remembered and given through an html form.